# Google Sheets: Send Slack message grabbing the text in a cell

Tags: google-sheets, slack, slack-api

I found a code that I linked to a button so that, when clicking it, a message is sent in Slack. So far I was only able to have that message within the code itself, as in here:

```
function sendNotification() {
  const url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/"
  const params = {
    method: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      "text":"Hello, World!"
    })
  }

  const sendMsg = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)
  var respCode = sendMsg.getResponseCode()
  Logger.log(sendMsg)
  Logger.log(respCode)
}
```

However, what I would want it to do is to grab the text from a cell, and send that as the message. Also, I don´t know if this would change anything, but the message in the cell comes up as the result of a formula un that cell, so it is the text that needs to go through, but not the formula.

If someone could help with this that would be awesome! TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the text from a specific cell, you can use [`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) and [`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue).

You can use the following example, just make sure to change the name of the sheet and the cell in the script:

```js
function sendNotification() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//Change the name of the sheet where you have the message
  let message = sheet.getRange("C1").getValue();//Change the cell where you have the message

  const url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/"
  const params = {
    method: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      "text":message
    })
  }

  const sendMsg = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)
  var respCode = sendMsg.getResponseCode()
  Logger.log(sendMsg)
  Logger.log(respCode)
}
```